# Redirect link to public website

Tags: web-services, facebook-apps

How do I change the link 'posted by' in a post to my fanpage? When a user clicks on this link he/she is redirected to the FB app that sent it. Is there a way to remove this or change it so the redirect will go to my public site? I'm using a Joomla component to post a page to FB true a FB application.

Answer (score 0):

Use a javascript to intercept clicks on that link, disable the default action and redirect to the new page.

Comment: Hi Michael,Thx for the reply. Can you give me a code snippet and where to implement this script?

Comment: I'd need to check your code for a more detailed answer. An easy way to manipulate events is using jQuery. You can select those links by class/id etc, and, on click, apply an event.preventDefault() and manipulate the link target.

Comment: BTW: how is this FB data retrieved? If the Joomla component uses a request to get that data from FB in real time, you may manipulate the response data in PHP before the script outputs it. Would be a faster/easier way.

Comment: Joomla (EasyBlog) is sending a blog post to a FB application. Application sends it to my FB page. After posting just at the bottom of this post there is a link "posted by..." this link is redirecting the post to the same FB application. My Q is how to remove this or change it to a link that will redirect the visitor to my public site.

Comment: Got it. There's no way to do that, because that's inserted by the FB application (and you can't manipulate that part of the output) and rendered in the FB page (and you can't access its elements by javascript). You may build a solution by NOT using the FB Application and using the FB API do directly send the blog post to your FB page. In this case, you'll be able to control all the output and to link back to your public site.